# How to use context object to make query in Class based View?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to understand class based views and having difficulty with variables.

```
class TeacherView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teacher
    context_object_name = 'the_object'

    template_name = urls['Teacher_detail'] # I declared an array and called urls to store template paths
```

I want to use the Teacher variable that I am going to use in the template to make queries.
Example:

```
Homeworks.objects.filter(Teacher = Teacher_of_this_view)
```

and pass also this Homeworks array to my template and use.

Can someone atleast please tell me what to check exactly ? I got lost with functions like get_object(), get_context_object() etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the *HomeWork* queryset to view by overriding the context data, as

```
class TeacherView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teacher
    context_object_name = 'the_object'
    template_name = urls['Teacher_detail']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["homeworks"] = Homeworks.objects.filter(Teacher=self.object)
        return context
```

Thus, you can access the qyeryset in the template as,

```
{% for homework in homeworks %}
    {{ homework }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function in your view:

```
class TeacherView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teacher
    context_object_name = 'the_object'
    template_name = urls['Teacher_detail']

    def homeworks(self):
        return Homeworks.objects.filter(Teacher=self.object)
```

in the view, you can then access this with `view.homeworks`, so for example:

```
{% for homework in view.homeworks %}
    {{ homework }}
{% endfor %}
```